# Will using more than one map () take more time than aggregating all logic in a single map () while using Stream?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

Here are two methods.`test1()` and `test2()`

```
public class MoreStreams {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Brad", "Kate", "Kim", "Jack",
                "Joe", "Mike", "Susan", "George", "Robert", "Julia", "Parker", "Benson");
        test1(names);
        //test2(names);
    }

    private static void test1(List<String> names) {
        List<String> result = names.stream()
                .map(name -> sub(toUpper(toLower(name))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static void test2(List<String> names) {
        List<String> result = names.stream()
                .map(MoreStreams::toLower)
                .map(MoreStreams::toUpper)
                .map(MoreStreams::sub)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static String toUpper(String name) {
        System.out.println("to Upper: " + name);
        return name.toUpperCase();
    }

    private static String toLower(String name) {
        System.out.println("to Lower: " + name);
        return name.toLowerCase();
    }

    private static String sub(String name) {
        System.out.println("to Title: " + name);
        return name.substring(1);
    }
}
```

The first one uses multiple `map()`, and the second one aggregates all logic together in one `map()`, do they take the same time or not, and why ? 
And what if there are more `map()`s in the chain? Please help me.

Comment: Is high performance is a serious concern? If not, focus on readability.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31058755/1553851)

Comment: Well did you test it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that will be called so few times that the jit compiler doesn`t have time to inline and optimize, the multimap would in theory be more expensive, due to the extra stackframes/method calls.

However, your main way to measure will require millions of invocations which will jit-compile and inline a lot these micro methods. They could very well end up be equal in performance.

Here is a pile of JVM args to show more of what's going on during your test. I'll let you net-search what they do.

```
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-Xloggc:"./gc.log"
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1M
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintCompilation
-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics
-XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions  -XX:+LogCompilation -XX:+PrintInlining
```

The last trio of optins are generating a log file consumable with "JitWatch", a gui program parsing and browsing all that stuff and telling you about jit events in a more friendly way.

You should design your test without the println of course.
Also, and this is VERY important, you should return a value for every test otherwise the JIT will figure you don`t use it and skip all your code!
Microbenchmarking is a science now! 
See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)