# Is it better to use a single flatMap() over a map().flatMap()?

Tags: java, java-stream, flatmap

I'm wondering if there is any significant difference between two cases of flatmapping.

**Case 1:**

```
someCollection
    .stream()
    .map(CollectionElement::getAnotherCollection)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream);
```

**Case 2:**

```
someCollection
    .stream()
    .flatMap(element -> element.getAnotherCollection().stream());
```

Which one should be prefered? Is any of these better in terms of performance?

Comment: I think it’s just the two ways the second one is the syntactic sugar!! To do the same this as first one!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple map functions vs. a block statement in a map in a java stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31058755/5221149)

Comment: They are doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which one should be preferred?

The difference is so cosmetic that it's up to you and your team - pick the one that you feel more comfortable with. I'd go for the second option, it's more concise.

> Is any of these better in terms of performance?

From the time complexity point of view, no. The first example involves a creation of a few unnecessary objects, so the second one is a more reasonable choice. 
However, keep in mind that we're talking about micro-optimizations here.

Comment: I'd add that the cosmetic differences may make a difference in terms of editability. It may be easier, for instance, to add a `filter` or another `map` between the calls to `map` and `flatMap` in the first example. Which might also be a disadvantage, but that would be a topic for codereview.stackexchange.com. And the 'conciseness' is also a matter of subjectivity ;-)

Comment: what are the objects that are created in the first example? I don't know Java's stream implementation well enough, but would it not optimise them out?

Comment: @Druckles all true but keep in mind that the above task is strictly about flattening the stream structure - if you need a filter/map in between, you could as well add it after the single flatMap call.

Regarding the additional costs in the second example, there's quite a lot happening even inside a single map() call to add another operation to the ReferencePipeline. So, not only you create another Stream object, another functional interface representation + code triggered by map() call. It will be optimized by JVM but at the end of the day, someone needs to collect the garbage